# How to stack these circles on top of each other in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Using D3.js, I've been trying to create a jar where circles (representing felt emotions) are stacked on top of each other. Unfortunately, they don't get stacked on top of each other, they simply overlap.

Here's my code:

```
var circle_counter = 0; // Global variable
var level_counter = 0; // Global variable

var circles = d3
.select("svg")
.selectAll("circle")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("circle")
.attr("cx", function(d) {
  if (circle_counter < 6) {
    d.cx = 62.5 + circle_counter * 45;
    circle_counter++;
    return d.cx;
  } else {
    level_counter++;
    circle_counter = 0;
    d.cx = 62.5 + circle_counter * 45;
    circle_counter++;
    return d.cx;
  }
})
.attr("cy", function(d) {
  if (level_counter == 0) {
    return (d.cy = 320);
  } else {
    return (d.cy = 320 - level_counter * 20);
  }
})
.attr("r", 20)
.attr("fill", function(d) {
  if (d.main_emotion == "anger") {
    return "red";
  } else if (d.main_emotion == "disgust") {
    return "green";
  } else if (d.main_emotion == "fear") {
    return "black";
  } else if (d.main_emotion == "happiness") {
    return "yellow";
  } else if (d.main_emotion == "sadness") {
    return "blue";
  } else {
    return "orange";
  }
})
.attr("fill-opacity", 0.5)
.attr("stroke", "white")
.attr("stroke-width", 3);
```

Here's what I'm getting:

Circles overlapping instead of laying on top of each other
[image]

And here's what I'm trying to achieve:

Circles laying on top of each other
[image]

How do I go about achieving this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I feel like the 'circles_counter' and/or the 'level_counter' variables are getting mixed-up somehow, but after numerous attempts at solving this problem, I don't have a clue as to what's wrong with my logic.

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: Hi @rioV8,

I've already tried a solution using the circles' id, but it actually complicates things and the end result is the same. As for having no idea on how D3.js and JavaScript work, well, I disagree, but that's not the point.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: it makes it much simpler

Comment: @rioV8 Can we first calculate `cx` and `cy` ,  create a dataset and then render the circles?

Comment: @sridharreddy don't hard code the position of the circles, soon he will use a scale and then all collapses. Next thing it has to run on a mobile.

Comment: @rioV8 okay got it...thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the right way to do it but I could achieve it. Before you use this code please go through the resources provided by D3 and check if there are any better ways.

```js
var data = [
            {main_emotion: 'sadness'},
            {main_emotion: 'happiness'},
            {main_emotion: 'fear'},
            {main_emotion: 'anger'},
            {main_emotion: 'disgust'},
        ]
        var dataSet = [];
        for(let i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i += 1) {
            for( let j = 0, len1 = data.length; j < len1; j += 1) {
                let newDataSet = {};
                const cx = 60 + (j * 45);
                const cy = 320 - (i * 45);
                newDataSet = {
                    ...data[j],
                    cx: cx,
                    cy: cy,
                }
                dataSet.push(newDataSet);
            }
        }
        var circles = d3
        .select("svg")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(dataSet)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return d.cx;
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return d.cy;
        })
        .attr("r", 20)
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
        if (d.main_emotion == "anger") {
            return "red";
        } else if (d.main_emotion == "disgust") {
            return "green";
        } else if (d.main_emotion == "fear") {
            return "black";
        } else if (d.main_emotion == "happiness") {
            return "yellow";
        } else if (d.main_emotion == "sadness") {
            return "blue";
        } else {
            return "orange";
        }
        })
        .attr("fill-opacity", 0.5)
        .attr("stroke", "white")
        .attr("stroke-width", 3)
    </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body {
        background: #999;
    }
</style>
<svg width=400 height=400></svg>
```